# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, tkinter, twisted

I'm quite a new programmer and I would be appreciated if you could help me. I have looked on the google but there are a few examples with "Twisted+Tkinter". When i click "Send" button on the window i get this error:

The error is 
e.insert(0,m)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'

And the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from twisted.internet import reactor, tksupport

class App(object):
    def onQuit(self):
        print "Quit!"
        reactor.stop()

    def onButton(self):
        m=self.entryvar.get()
        e=self.labeltext.get()
        e.insert(0,m)

def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.entryvar=StringVar()
    self.mes=Entry(frame,textvariable=self.entryvar)
    self.mes.pack()

    self.labeltext=StringVar()
    self.label=Label(frame,textvariable=self.labeltext)
    self.label.pack()

    q = Button(frame, text="Quit!", command=self.onQuit)
    b = Button(frame, text="Send", command=self.onButton)
    q.pack(side=LEFT)
    b.pack(side=LEFT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    tksupport.install(root)
    app = App(root)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call `insert()`? You are manipulating a label string as if it is a mutable list, but a `str` is not a mutable sequence type.

Comment: I'am trying to change the text on the label "labeltext" with the entry "entryvar"

Comment: For what it's worth this seems to have nothing to do with Twisted.

Comment: I am just testing it, if i could solve this problem i'll apply it on twisted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the `labeltext` `StringVar`, you need to construct a *new* string value for it. `str` is an *immutable* sequence type, and unlike `list` cannot be modified in-place.

In this case, perhaps you meant to use string concatenation? The following code will set `labeltext` to `m + e`, where `e` is the previous contents of `labeltext`, effectively prepending `m`:

```
def onButton(self):
    m=self.entryvar.get()
    e=self.labeltext.get()
    self.labeltext.set(m + e)
```

Comment: Thank you, the error is disappeared but nothing's happened on the window. Any idea?

Comment: @billwild: Does `entryvar` *have* a value? If it is empty, then `labeltext` will appear unchanged. You could try debugging this by changing the `.set()` call to `self.labeltext.set('m: ' + m + ', e: ' + e)`, for example.

Comment: Should i make self.entryvar=StringVar() /n self.entryvar.set("something")

Comment: @billwild: No, why would you need to do that? You are merely *reading* `entryvar`.

Comment: I don't know what i'm doing, please just instruct me.

Comment: @billwild: Sorry, I don't know what you are doing either. Once you figure that out, you can perhaps ask a *new* question with the next specific problem you run into.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace Label text with Entry text

```
 def onButton(self):
    entry_text = self.entryvar.get()
    self.labeltext.set(entry_text)
```

Or if you want to add entry text before label text

```
 def onButton(self):
    entry_text = self.entryvar.get()
    label_text = self.labeltext.get()
    self.labeltext.set(entry_text + " " + label_text)
```

Comment: The error is disappeared but nothing's happened on the window